# blur not working in safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, blur

I'm looking to detect clicks in an iframe and based on this answer posted here a while ago (http://jsfiddle.net/oqjgzsm0/), I've got this piece of code working for all browsers except safari 9. For some reason, safari seems to not detect the elem.blur(); and keeps looping the action (in this case, a function call to refresh another iframe). Any ideas on how I can make this solution work for safari as well?

```
function reload() {
    document.getElementById('iframe#2').src += '';
} 

var monitor = setInterval(function(){
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.id == 'iframe#1'){
       reload();

       elem.blur(monitor);
       return false;
   } 
}, 100);
```

Comment: Why are you calling blur with your function instead of clearInterval as in the example you're following?

Comment: The clearinterval only allows one click in iframe1 for one refresh in iframe2. To enable multiple clicks and refreshes, blur works well..except in safari 9 :(

Comment: also, as a workaround, I just realized that if I click anywhere outside iframe1, the refresh loop stops in safari 9. Maybe simulate a click outside the iframe?